# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on server start up

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I am using JBOSS EAP 6.4 for my development. Here I have two war files. One is say myProject, and another is myProject-ws. myProject is a spring MVC application which is working perfectly on its own. Here I have used Spring @Service for creating my service layer.

Now problem is, I am trying to add SOAP web services. This SOAP webservices war is supposed to refer to java beans of my spring MVC project. But when I am running the server I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError .

Till now I have attempted following things -

1. Add Spring MVC project in the build path
2. Add Spring MVC project in the project references
3. Add Spring MVC project in the class path.

Even after all this changes, I am getting same exception. Is there any thing else which I can do?

Thanks

Comment: can you paste with the exact stack trace ?

Comment: you will also need to provide paths to the Spring config files in Porject1.

Comment: Read here to find out possible causes of this exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Answer (score -1):

You need to import the spring bean context of the underlying project myProject in the parent project myProject-ws context initializer as it would be deployed as the war.
for example if you are using xml bean declaration ,then import the myProject bean declaration xml in the xml spring beans declaration in the myProject-ws project.

if using annotation then use the @import in the configuration file of myProject-ws project.